# Did J.F. Sebastian work from home?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner

I know he stated that he "does genetic design work for the Tyrell Corporation", but he also has quite the hobbyist operation going on in his home laboratory. I wonder if he physically travels to the Tyrell offices to work or if he works from home?

[image: concept art of J.F Sebastian's home Laboratory]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [earlier version](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Blade-Runner.html) of the script heavily implies that although Sebastian has regular contact with Tyrell, he's some sort of independent contractor (like Chew, the "I just do eyes" man we see in the previous scene). His bus is described as an "*ambulance*" and has the words "*Animoid Express*" written on the side, evidently his own company.

Although this is removed from the [later screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Blade-Runner.html) (where he's described as being an employee with higher level clearance), there's no special reason to assume that Sebastian doesn't work from home, in his extensively appointed laboratory and only visiting Tyrell's building infrequently:

> **BATTY:** *... your friend, the man who owns this building?*
>
> **SEBASTIAN:** *Dr. Tyrell?*
>
> Batty nods.
>
> **SEBASTIAN:** *He's not really my friend.  I just do a job for him now and then.*
>
> ...
>
> **BATTY:** *When do you deliver your project?*
>
> **SEBASTIAN:** *This afternoon.*

Comment: Incredible answer. Although I'm sure J.F. has a daily routine of some kind, I don't believe him to be an actual full time employee of Tyrell. thank you!

Comment: @whitebox - In the earlier script, he's actually coming back from meeting Chew (the eye-guy) to collect some supplies and Pris hides in the back of his van. That explains why he's out and about.

Answer (score 2):

In the movie he is shown coming home from somewhere.  The audience is not told specifically that he is coming home from work but he does have a ritual of his "friends" greeting him with "Home again, home again".  He also has access to the Tyrell Corporation building, he is familiar with how to get in and get past security.  Although he may have telecommuted on occasion, it is likely he went to work at a different place than his home.

Comment: I have an access card for my head office. I've never used it.