# Why would Tyrell allow a dangerous replicant like Roy Batty to visit him?

Tags: blade-runner, blade-runner-series

In Blade Runner, Eldon Tyrell allows an employee to bring a dangerous soldier replicant to Tyrell's personal apartment. Why would he allow that?

He knew Roy Batty was a super soldier replicant. Very strong. Very intelligent. Very cunning.

He knew Batty was willing to kill humans and had already killed humans to escape to Earth.

He knew even an unarmed Batty could kill him.

He knew Batty was in the elevator. (What super wealthy super powerful business leaders do not put security cameras in the few ways in or out of their apartments? The Tyrell company had facial pictures of all replicants since the cop boss showed the pictures to Deckard near the start of the movie.)

Knowing all that, why did he allow any replicant to visit him? He allowed not just any, but Roy Batty.

Comment: Please be aware that we have tags for `blade-runner-2049` and `blade-runner-series`. (I'm commenting as I'm unfamiliar with the series but given the timing of your question I would assume it's about the new film suffixed 2049 rather than the original

Comment: @Edlothiad by character names he mentioned it seems to be original film only not sequel

Comment: @Edlothiad There is no need for the two tags you mentioned. The question is only about the original film.

Comment: @RichS, from the `blade-runner-series` tag wiki, "*For use when referring to any part of the Blade Runner franchise. Should be used in conjunction with either [blade-runner] or [blade-runner-2049] tags.*" so although it doesn't need the `blade-runner-2049` tag it does need the `blade-runner-series` tag

Comment: Note that while BR imagines a 2019 world, it was created in 1982,when video surveillance was JUST gaining ground and still used analogue devices and methods of viewing. It is quite  possible that in 1982 nobody even thought cameras would be installed EVERYWHERE as it is now. Besides, with the technology of the times, putting a [comparatively] bulky camera in a moving contraption might make it seem somewhat less realistic.

Comment: Who knows what kind of private vices Tyrell might have? It's possible he regularly has certain visitors he doesn't want to be known to his security staff.

Comment: More importantly when Roy asked for more life, I wondered why didn't Tyrell say "Uh, yeah we're working on that. Let me get back to you."

Comment: @zabeus Because Roy would know Tyrell was lying. First, Roy was probably as intelligent, or more, as the engineers that created him, as the opening crawl indicates. Also, during Roy's dialogue with his maker, he shows he has already been thinking about the problem, so I think he wouldn't be easily fooled by Tyrell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> He knew Batty was in the elevator.

He did not know Batty was in the elevator, at least not in [the script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/blade-runner_shooting.html).

It's not clear if the "speaker" is an AI or a "dumb" computer system, whether it's a surveillance system at all, or what it is, but it only announces that J.F. Sebastian is in the elevator (both in the script and the film):

```
                             SPEAKER
              Quinzieme Blue entry.  A Mr. J.F.
              Sebastian, one-six-four-one-seven.
```

When Sebastian and Batty enter, it's at least made obvious in the script that Tyrell was not expecting Batty:

```
     INT. TYRELL'S BEDROOM - NIGHT

    Tyrell is standing at the chess board in his nightgown
    staring at the pieces in a fit of concentration.  He
    doesn't look up at the sound of footsteps.

                            SEBASTIAN
              I....uh.... I brought a friend.

    Tyrell looks alarmed.

    Batty is standing in the shadows.

    Tyrell is reaching for a tasseled bell pull that hangs
    over his bed.

    Batty's eyes are like little coals glowing.

    Warned by the look, Tyrell abandons the bell pull and
    reaches under the sheets for something.

                            BATTY
              To act without understanding
              could lead to the very thing
              the act seeks to avoid.

    What's in Batty's eyes completes the warning.

    Tyrell decides to heed it.  If he's scared though, he
    does a good job of concealing it.
```

[In the film, this scene is slightly different](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5Oqf4NfAIk): Sebastian enters with Batty, and he says "I....uh.... I brought a friend" like in the script. However, Tyrell does not look very alarmed, and he doesn't reach for a tasseled bell pull or anything (a weapon?) under the sheets; he just says "I'm... surprised you didn't come here sooner".

However, it seems clear to me that he's still alarmed here. He hesitates a little when seeing Batty. He stares at the pair and then looks away pensively. He also hesitates a little when delivering his next line, "What... What seems to be the problem?". I think the implication is that "he does a good job of concealing" his alarm, just like in the script.

Comment: In that case, he did not know. Points out a glaring oversight in his security to allow an employee to bring a friend into his home without prior approval from security.

Comment: @LincolnMan Yes. Not even an employee, but [an independent contractor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90774/did-j-f-sebastian-work-from-home/90853#90853).

Comment: +1 It's quite obvious Tyrell didn't know in either the script or the film. As for why he doesn't seem (extremely) alarmed, it's likely that he is alarmed but knows there's no way out at that point. Also, pretty sure he admires his creation and his curiosity is piqued, so he may as well see where the situation goes.

Answer (score 2):

Hubris...

Tyrell is, essentially, Batty's creator (even if not directly). He acts like a proud father when talking to Batty - *what harm can my prodigal son do to me?*

Tyrell also demonstrates this innate self-pride when talking with Deckard following Rachael's V-K test - and it seems to be blinding him from the consequences of creating something so close to human.

Answer (score 1):

It's made clear in the film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/122327.Blade_Runner) that Tyrell was unaware of the presence of Sebastian's '*friends*'.

> Tyrell was still peering intently at his precarious position on the
> board when the door to his bedroom opened.
>
> "I've brought ... a friend,” said Sebastian, and Batty stepped past
> him. Tyrell's hand moved quickly toward a tasseled bellpull hanging
> over his bed. A burning look from Batty stopped him cold.
>
> <sub><sup>[Blade Runner: A Story of the Future](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/122327.Blade_Runner)</sup></sub>

The film's [shooting script](https://s://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/blade-runner_shooting.html) has him distracted by Sebastian's sudden and unexpected prowess at the chess game they're playing.

> INT. TYRELL'S BEDROOM - NIGHT
>
> Tyrell is standing at the chess board in his nightgown
> staring at the pieces in a fit of concentration.  He
> doesn't look up at the sound of footsteps.
>
> **SEBASTIAN:** *I....uh.... I brought a friend.*
>
> Tyrell looks alarmed.
> Batty is standing in the shadows.
> Tyrell is reaching for a tasseled bell pull that hangs
> over his bed.
> Batty's eyes are like little coals glowing.
> Warned by the look, Tyrell abandons the bell pull and
> reaches under the sheets for something.
>
> **BATTY:** *To act without understanding could lead to the very thing the act seeks to avoid.*
>
> What's in Batty's eyes completes the warning.
> Tyrell decides to heed it.  If he's scared though, he does a good job of concealing it.